# More on ui-grid row filtering

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

### Long version of the question

I have a complex filtering operation that I'm trying to implement for a ui-grid application.  Essentially, I have a big grid with lots of columns, each having the typical filter fields at the top of the columns.  That works great.

Then I have an extra analysis step that the user can turn on (which involves looking for sets of rows that meet a certain criterion, and then marking rows visible or not based on the results) that *MUST* be applied logically after all the other filters (i.e. it does share 'commutative property' as all the column-top filters do).   This extra analysis/filter step intends to take the row set that is produced by the column-top filters and then apply this one final, mother-of-all-complex-filtration steps.

I am able to get that filtration logic to produce initially correct results - when the user first clicks into the special mode, I perform the analysis and save the necessary info in a hidden column of the grid; and then a RowsProcessor sets the row.visible attribute accordingly.  (perhaps I didn't need the RowsProcessor, and maybe I could have just set the visibility in the analysis subroutine.)  But whatever - the point is that the rows are marked visible or not.  The problem occurs when the user *subsequently* adds/removes/changes a filter to one of the column top filters.  That extra analysis step by necessity needs to be based upon the rows that are visible according to the column-top-filters.  And the first time into the special filtering routine, a call to `gridApi.core.getVisibleRows()` returns exactly  that rowset.  But after that, the visible rowset is now reduced by the prior execution of the special filtering.  But I need to get back to the rowset (i.e. complete recalculation of the row.visible attributes) of just the column-top-filters, without any special final filtration.    Is there a way to do that - to effectively undo the filtration effects of the RowsProcessor?

### Short version of the question

**Is there some way to force recalculation of the visible row set based on the column top filters?  and to do so in a way to get control back so additional filtration steps can be executed?**

I've looked at various things in the APIs but cannot tell which, if any, might help me.  For example:

- In the ui.grid (Grid) portion of the API, I see many different flavors of refresh methods that may help, but there's no distinction given that I understand.  I hope the one that I need is not `refreshRows( )` that says "not functional at present"
- Also, the `GridRow` 'class' seems to have various methods that speak of
  visibility "overrides" - that sounds possibly like what I might need 
  (my final visibility result possibly being an override to those calculated by the column-top filters).  But I tried using those methods instead of directly setting row.visible and I did not see any difference.

Can anyone suggest a direction for me to try?

and even better, is there any written description that provides a high-level overview of ui-grid functionality? I love the package, but using it for the first time, I'm just having a hard time with what are probably basic concepts, and possibly I'm thinking about this problem all wrong.

Once again, thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever the rowsProcessors run they start by setting all rows to visible, then each rowsProcessor runs in turn with the results from the previous rowsProcessor being passed to the next one.  RowsProcessors have a priority, so you can set your processor to run at the appropriate place in the sequence.

It sounds like your problem is that you're using getVisibleRows to calculate what to do, rather than looking at the rows that are passed in to your rows processor, and evaluating based on which rows are visible in that input.

My guess is that you would be better to set your rowsProcessor to have a high (late) priority, and then process all your calculations within that processor rather than attempting to cache them on the data set itself.  If you need to extract the visible rows from the set of renderableRows that are passed to your processor, you could do it with:

```
var visibleRows = renderableRows.filter( function(row) { return row.visible; });
```

Comment: Thank you again Paul.  Your description gave me a better/deeper understanding of how ui-grid works, and your diagnosis was correct that the net effect of my implementation needed correcting so that the calculation runs off rows passed into the rows processor.  With a little reworking, things appear to be working! thx